# Undefined method 'detect' for :"Model#property":Symbol. Bad self-referential Neo4j model definitions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, jruby, neo4j

When running unit tests I get the following error for some of my tests:

```
     6) Error:
test_name_can't_be_nil(NodeTest):
NoMethodError: undefined method `detect' for :"Node#children":Symbol
    /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7.2/gems/activemodel-3.1.4/lib/active_model/naming.rb:85:in `model_name'
    /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7.2/gems/activemodel-3.1.4/lib/active_model/errors.rb:315:in `generate_message'
    org/jruby/RubyArray.java:2339:in `collect'
    /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7.2/gems/activemodel-3.1.4/lib/active_model/errors.rb:314:in `generate_message'
    /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7.2/gems/activemodel-3.1.4/lib/active_model/errors.rb:235:in `add'
    /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7.2/gems/activemodel-3.1.4/lib/active_model/errors.rb:256:in `add_on_blank'
    org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1615:in `each'
    /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7.2/gems/activemodel-3.1.4/lib/active_model/errors.rb:254:in `add_on_blank'
    /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7.2/gems/activemodel-3.1.4/lib/active_model/validations/presence.rb:9:in `validate'
    org/jruby/RubyBasicObject.java:1704:in `__send__'
    org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2101:in `send'
    /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7.2/gems/activesupport-3.1.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:306:in `_callback_before_47'
    /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7.2/gems/activesupport-3.1.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:410:in `_run_validate_callbacks'
    org/jruby/RubyBasicObject.java:1698:in `__send__'
    org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2097:in `send'
    /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7.2/gems/activesupport-3.1.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
    /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7.2/gems/activemodel-3.1.4/lib/active_model/validations.rb:212:in `run_validations!'
    /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7.2/gems/activemodel-3.1.4/lib/active_model/validations.rb:179:in `valid?'
    /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7.2/gems/neo4j-2.0.1-java/lib/neo4j/rails/validations.rb:29:in `valid?'
    /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7.2/gems/neo4j-2.0.1-java/lib/neo4j/rails/callbacks.rb:26:in `valid_with_callbacks?'
    /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7.2/gems/activesupport-3.1.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run_validation_callbacks'
    /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7.2/gems/neo4j-2.0.1-java/lib/neo4j/rails/callbacks.rb:26:in `valid_with_callbacks?'
    /Users/dave/Projects/myapp/test/test_helper.rb:11:in `assert_presence'
    /Users/dave/Projects/myapp/test/unit/node_test.rb:9:in `test_name_can't_be_nil'
    org/jruby/RubyBasicObject.java:1698:in `__send__'
```

The offending test in question is:

```rb
class NodeTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
    def assert_presence( model, field)
        model.send( (field.to_s + '='), nil )
        model.valid?
        assert_match /can not be blank/, model.errors[field].join,
        "Presence error for #{field} not found on #model.class"
    end
    def setup
        @node = FactoryGirl.build :node
    end

    test "name can't be nil" do
        assert_presence @node, :name
    end
    ....
end
```

Where Nodes are defined in the model as:

```rb
class Node < Neo4j::Rails::Model
    include Neo4j::NodeMixin

    property :name, type: String, index: :exact
    property :description, type: String

    has_one(:creator).from(User, :created_nodes)

    has_n(:children).to(Node)              ## <--- Suspected difficult line
    has_n(:parents).from(Node, :children)  ## <--- Suspected difficult line
    has_n(:capable_users).from(User, :capabilities)

    # The following has the Class commented out because this somehow triggers
    # an error from the 'has_n(:children).to(Node)' line
    has_n(:challenges)  #.to(Challenge)
    ....
end
```

Basically, the server can run fine, but will crash anytime I try to call valid? on a Node (not other models). Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Comment: Probably does not make a difference, but you should not include the NodeMixin

Comment: Another thing, instead of using Constants like Challenge use strings instead, e.g. has_n(:challenges).to("Challenge")

Comment: That's unexpected, the documentation at http://neo4j.rubyforge.org/guides/rails3.html#mapping-nodes-and-relationships uses the constant. And you're right, it didn't change things, but if you say so I'll start using strings from now.

Also what's the deal with no mixin, what is [this](http://neo4j.rubyforge.org/guides/mapping.html) site referring to?

Great gem, btw.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was my choice of attributes, namely parents (and maybe children).

I took a look at the source in active model where the error was occurring ([here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.1.4/activemodel/lib/active_model/naming.rb#L85)), and saw this:

```
def model_name
  @_model_name ||= begin
    namespace = self.parents.detect { |n| n.respond_to?(:_railtie) }  # <--- this line
    ActiveModel::Name.new(self, namespace)
  end
end
```

As you can see, parents appears to be in use. I changed the names and the validations, saving, etc, now works.